# Appropiate position of prime in a LaTeX formula

Tags: mathtools

I'm using this code in LaTeX:

```
$\vec{s}^{'}$
```

The result:

[image]

As you see, the position of `'` isn't good. How can I have a appropriate position?

Comment: You don't have to use `'` in a superscript. How about `\vec{s}'`?

Comment: Maybe \vec{s'}?

Comment: Using `^{'}` is always wrong.

Comment: @Manual appearance of `\vec{s}'` is same.

Comment: @Mark. We need prime for both `S` and arrow.

Comment: try `{\vec{s}}'`.

Comment: @barbarabeeton. Same. I Think the prime position isn't appropriate in all answers.

Comment: one more variation: `\vec{s}{}'` -- and i agree that this does leave a lot to be desired.

Comment: @barbarabeeton . Same in $\vec{s}{}'$ format.

Comment: okay, this should do it (even if it's ugly): `\vec{s}^{\,\prime}`,  by the way, the results of my testing (finally) didn't get anything that looked quite like what's in your example, so presumably document class and packages matter.

Comment: That's better barbara. Thanks. Please add it to answers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

it seems that there isn't any "nice" way to handle this.
the first four attempts failed miserably.  only the last output is passable,
and the code is ugly.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\[
  \vec{s}' \quad
  {\vec{s}}' \quad
  \vec{s}{}' \quad
  {\vec{s}}{}' \quad
  \vec{s}^{\,\prime}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image: output of example code]

Comment: `\vec{s}\,'` is simpler markup, although perhaps the space is a little too big compared to your last

Comment: @DavidCarlisle -- i did consider that, and liked the tighter space better.  (nothing is perfect.)